# Unable to disable JavaFX Canvas's Antialiasing

Tags: java, javafx, canvas

I am currently working on a MS Paint-like application. I am using a flood fill algorithm for the bucket option, but the problem is that ,since all shapes drawn by the Canvas's GraphicalContext are antialiased, I get this result: [Filling a drawn out shape](https://i.stack.imgur.com/psLXD.png)

So to disable it I have tried the following:

- Setting the SceneAntialiasing variable inside of the Scene constructor to SceneAntialiasing.DISABLED -
  `new Scene(root,800,600,false,SceneAntialiasing.DISABLED)`
- Using the `.setImageSmoothing(boolean)` method of GraphicsContext with a`false` argument.
- Setting the X and Y coordinates of the shapes to `int` values in order not to use "half pixels".

I have also searched all over the internet but there is little to no information regarding this matter.
Has anyone had a simmular issue? Is there a workoround to it or should I instead just write my own shape drawing methods? Any toughts on the matter are greatly appreaciated!

Comment: See the "Interaction with Coordinate Systems" section in the [Javadocs for `Shape`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/15/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/shape/Shape.html). Since integer coordinates correspond to the boundary of pixels, you might actually want to set the coordinates to an integer plus `0.5` (or use a stroke width of 2 with integer coordinates).

Comment: @James_D Thank you for the answer! I used your suggestions to set the width to 2 or add 0.5 to the coordinates and I was able to create some non-aliased lines. However I was only able to make it work for perfectly straight lines(lines that have one coordinate that is the same). For non-straigh lines and shapes like ellipse for exampe, the problem unfortunately still persists.